# How do I distinguish a particular source from a random source?

Tags: normal-distribution

I have generator $\mathcal{A}$ which generates each iteration a binary pairs $(x,y)$ where $P(x=0)=\frac{1}{2}(1+\epsilon_1)$ and $P(y=0)=\frac{1}{2}(1+\epsilon_2)$. Also both co-ordinates are independent to each other. I want to distinguish $\mathcal{A}$ from random source $\mathcal{B}$. If we consider only first co-ordinate, we need $\frac{2}{\epsilon_1^2}$ call of generator. What kind of event should we consider to reduce the number of calls?

Comment: Welcome to CV! Since you’re new here, you may want to take our tour, which has information for new users.  Since this looks like homework (apologies if it's not), please add the [self-study] tag and read its wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing. If this is self-study rather than homework, let us know, and... it's still a good idea to show us what you've tried.

Comment: I fail to see how you deduce you only need $1/\epsilon^2_1$ calls to the generator to distinguish it from the other one.  Consider $P(x=0) = 1$, where $\epsilon_1 = 1$.  Can you really tell from just one call, where you observed $x=0$, that the call is from $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: Sorry, it should be 2/\epsilon_1^2. Kindly see Theorem 2 of https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-45473-X_13.pdf

Comment: Please add new info/corrections as an edit to the post. Comments are read by few people, and we want posts to be self-contained.